# run a url on command line without using curl or wget content on same server

Tags: php, get

The background to this is I have a function on a website i wish to run once a day, the cron and website or on the same server. My website is using cloudflare and my cron runs the curl command to run the function. This works about 50% of the time, the other 50% i get a 522 cloudflare error. So I need to bypass cloudlfare really to run this.

So lets say my curl was https://my-site.com/index.php?action=do-task and the path on the server to the index.php file is var/www/html/index.php

how is the best way to do this so the do-task action is passed into the index.php file?

i'm thinking something like

```
php /var/www/html/index.php
```

might work but can't work out how i would pass the action = do-task part

thanks

Craig

Comment: you can do `curl http://localhost/index.php?action=do-task` this way it doesn't go outside the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the page is already using `$_GET` then check for command line arguments, make them into a query string and parse them into `$_GET`:

```
if(isset($argv)) { parse_str(implode('&', $argv), $_GET); }
```

Then call your script like this:

```
php /var/www/html/index.php action=do-task
```

`$_GET` will contain:

```
Array
(
    [index_php] =>
    [action] => do-task
)
```

For more parameters just separate with a space:

```
php /var/www/html/index.php action=do-task foo=bar
```